# Scala spark to filter out reoccurring zero values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe in spark with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rate: decimal(32,16) (nullable =true)
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable =true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Data is like this in my schema

```
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
|   user_id|  rate    |date         | type    |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-20   | A       |         
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-21   |  A      |         
| XO_121   | 30       |2020-04-22   |      A  |        
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-23   |       A |      
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-24   |       A |        
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-25   |      A  |        
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-26   |       A |       
| XO_121   |5         |2020-04-27   |   A     |
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-28   |      A  |        
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-29   |       A |       
| XO_121   |1         |2020-04-30   |   A     |
```

I want to save space so I want to skip rate which has zero value but just want it's initial occurrence only other rate duplicates are allowed like you see case of 10 and they need to preserve Date order . So after applying filter my data should look like this

```
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
|   user_id|  rate    |date         | type    |
+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-20   | A       |         
| XO_121   | 10       |2020-04-21   |  A      |         
| XO_121   | 30       |2020-04-22   |      A  |        
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-23   |       A |          
| XO_121   |5         |2020-04-27   |   A     |   
| XO_121   |0         |2020-04-28   |      A  | 
| XO_121   |1         |2020-04-30   |      A  |
```

I'm new to spark so just want to find out way to filter . I used Rank concept but that don't work .If any body can provide solution to this problem

Comment: you want to preserve first `0` per user_id ? , or overall just single `0` rate record?

Comment: Preserve first zero

Comment: I mean, what will be output for `(XO_121,10), (XO_121,0),(XO_121,0),  (XO_300,0)` ?

Comment: For a particular id say XO_121 for multiple continuous date we have zero so we will skip later ones just keep the first zero value.
Same goes for XO_300

Comment: thank you for the clarification. posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Preparation :

```
val df = Seq( ("XO_121","10","2020-04-20"),("XO_121","10","2020-04-21"),("XO_121","30","2020-04-22"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-23"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-24"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-25"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-26"),("XO_121","5","2020-04-27"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-28"),("XO_121","0","2020-04-29"),("XO_121","1","2020-04-30"))
.toDF("user_id","rate","date")
```

Get the previous value of rate, and check for each record `"rate" === "0" && "previous_rate" === "0"`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val winSpec = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("date")

val finalDf = df.withColumn("previous_rate", lag("rate", 1).over(winSpec))
.filter( !($"rate" === "0" && $"previous_rate" === "0"))
.drop("previous_rate")
```

Output :

```
scala> finalDf.show
+-------+----+----------+
|user_id|rate|      date|
+-------+----+----------+
| XO_121|  10|2020-04-20|
| XO_121|  10|2020-04-21|
| XO_121|  30|2020-04-22|
| XO_121|   0|2020-04-23|
| XO_121|   5|2020-04-27|
| XO_121|   0|2020-04-28|
| XO_121|   1|2020-04-30|
+-------+----+----------+
```

Now you can apply `orderBy($"date")` or `orderBy($"userd_id",$"date")` which ever is applicable for you.

Comment: Simple & easy to understand your solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() instead of Rank as below

```
_w = W.partitionBy("col2").orderBy("col1")
df = df.withColumn("rnk", F.row_number().over(_w))
df = df.filter(F.col("rnk") == F.lit("1"))
df.show()
+------+----+---+
|  col1|col2|rnk|
+------+----+---+
|XO_121|   0|  1|
|XO_121|  10|  1|
|XO_121|  30|  1|
|XO_121|  20|  1|
|XO_121|  40|  1|
+------+----+---+
```

**Also , you can use first() in case you know there is only repetition on value 0**

```
df = df.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(F.first("col2").alias("col2")).orderBy("col2")
df.show()
+------+----+----+
|  col1|col2|col2|
+------+----+----+
|XO_121|   0|   0|
|XO_121|  10|  10|
|XO_121|  20|  20|
|XO_121|  30|  30|
|XO_121|  50|  50|
+------+----+----+
```